# how do I select the div that has this <i> using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to scrape a quiz with selenium using python, here's the code for 1 answer choice.

the   will contains this specific class when it's correct answer , and when its not correct it is another class for this

so I want to get the text of the question where the answer is correct (The product's impact on customer satisfaction.)
It will depends of the class inside the  < i > (because as I said, when its false answer, it's another class inside )

But I can't find how to select it with XPATH

```
<div class='course-player__interactive-checkbox _interactive-checkbox_cjbh9b'>
  <div class='course-player__interactive-checkbox__choice-label _interactive-checkbox__choice-label_cjbh9b'>
    <span class='course-player__interactive-checkbox__choice-letter _interactive-checkbox__choice-letter_cjbh9b'> ANSWER A </span>
  </div>
  <span class='course-player__interactive-checkbox__choice-text _interactive-checkbox__choice-text_cjbh9b'> The product's impact on customer satisfaction. </span>
  <span class='course-player__interactive-checkbox__choice-answered _interactive-checkbox__choice-answered_cjbh9b'>
    <i class='toga-icon toga-icon-circle-fill-check _interactive-checkbox__choice-icon_cjbh9b'> </i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to retrieve the string

> The product's impact on customer satisfaction.

with Selenium is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("file:///input.html")
lookup = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div/span[i]/preceding-sibling::*[1]")
print(lookup[0].text)
```

The XPath-1.0 expression selects the `<span>` before the `<span>` which has an `<i>` child.
But be aware that this code does not contain any error handling.

Comment: i'm not sure its correct, what I meant was that sometimes the class for the <i> will change because it is a false answer.
Imagine a question with 4 choices : the code I wrote before is for a correct answer.
But the 3 others will be false and the class of the <i> then, will be a bit different. 
So here I think I'd like to select the span which has an <i> child with this specifi class ?

Comment: You can make the expression more specific like `//div/span[i[contains(@class,'toga-icon-circle-fill-check')]]/preceding-sibling::*[1]`, for example. Is that closer to what you want? You're not very clear on what conditions should be met.

Comment: I cannot know the correct value for the @class string, of course....